# How to autocomplete a query using "GoogleAutoComplete" API in Swift IOS?

Tags: swift, autocomplete

Could somebody help me with a source code that how to `autocomplete` a query using `GoogleAutoComplete` API in swift IOS?

I have already gone through a lot but nothing worked?

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vinoth. I have followed some tutorials here is the reference.
http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/

Also I searched on github platform please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find plenty of `Swift` code about the `Place Autocomplete` feature of the `Google Places API`, there are also a few screenshots to help you out. To view Swift code just select it from the code selector snippet

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#customize_text_and_background_colors